# Weed that looks like grass

Tags: weed-control, grass, weeds

I cannot seem to get rid of this weed that looks like grass. Can anyone tell me what this is

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Call the chickens. they'll take care of it.

Comment: Are you saying that chickens can distinguish between different species of grass and eat one over the other?  Come on...

Answer (score 5):

Get a little bottle of roundup and a pair of rubber gloves.  Carefully wet your glove covered fingers and stroke a bit of glyphosate/roundup onto the leaves of this...crab grass.  It will take a few weeks to kill the entire plant as this glyphosate is systemic and is transported to the roots where it kills the roots. Apply more if there is viable plant growth happening. Be very very careful NOT to spray, not to drip on any other plant material!  Digging this grass up would be a waste of time.  Keep the grass height NO LESS THAN 3".  Your grass near the concrete is getting fried because it is too short and too near a major heat sink.  Water deeply, allow to dry out before watering again.

Comment: I always keep the grass cut high on #4 because i know if you cut it too short the sun will burn it. I think it is because michigan has had a very hot late spring or early summer. So round up basically using gloves?  What is this weed?  Its taking over my entire lawn.

Comment: I think it is a bunch grass weed such as crab grass.  I'd have to see the roots and a closeup of the crown (where the leaves originate) and leaves...flowers would be so nice.  Roundup and neem are pretty much the only pesticides (herbicides lumped under same label) I've ever used, even the years maintaining commercial, residential landscapes.  Try to get a flat piece of cardboard to sit upon, wear rubber gloves (read literature about clothing for types of gloves), have a tiny little dish of roundup (already diluted to proper strength)...you could even use a tiny brush instead of wet fingers.

Comment: Go slowly...grins.  Also, make sure it is a very calm dead wind day.  Do not mow before doing this.  The more vigorous and larger surface area will transport the glyphosate to the roots better.  It'll take 2 to 3 weeks for complete kill and a week from now I'd go out with the gloves and little brush and cardboard to paint any green growth that looks healthy...of these weed grasses.  Send more pics to be able to ID, but this is pretty standard.  Can't use fertilizer with herbicide bad idea anyway as this is not broadleaf it is another grass.

Comment: And you need to sharpen your mower blades...see the fried ends of the grasses?  Will dull the look of your lawn and think of all that hard work you've put into that lawn.  Also is a good area for disease...after these grasses die there is nothing more you need or should do.  They become organic matter.

Comment: can you recommend some gloves?  Will these do: https://www.amazon.com/Wells-Lamont-167L-Heavyweight-Gauntlet/dp/B000BZ8K4M/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1467906341&sr=8-1&keywords=mens+rubber+gloves

Comment: Well, those sound like expensive gloves...just make sure that they are for chemicals, non-reactive.  You can get cheap ones at Lowes or similar.  I just used rubber maid...I am not that worried about glyphosate.  Main thing is to have ease of movement.  Read the material that comes with Round up.   Even us licensed pesticide applicators have to read the label on any pesticide/herbicide 5X  each and every time we use a product.  The gauntlet type is what you want as that stops drips going up your sleeves.  But I'd hope you would only have a teensy tiny bottle or dish to work with, no drips!!

Comment: Can you post a link to the gloves?

Comment: Look up gloves chemical resistant/proof.  You could even use a tiny paint brush...water color paint brush, still use gloves.  Simple latex rubbermaid gloves is enough if you aren't soaking your hands in glyphosate.  Lay out newspaper around these areas for just in case.  I just wanted to reply to one of your comments; you said you thought that cutting grass too short would cause it to get burned by the sun/heat.  That is not the problem.  These grass species have large root systems.  Large root systems need enough photosynthetic growth to support or else the grass is stressed ( 3" no shorter).

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a grass and may be hay of some sort. Could be fescue but the leaf looks finer to me like brome, timothy or orchard grass. Unfortunately, you can't spray it because the chemical that kills it will kill your other grass. I don't believe it is nutsedge. After looking at it, probably is K-31 which doesn't look good next to you bluegrass. Broadleaf and all, I hate it. Its hardy but I try to kill as much of it as I can. It is invasive!

Answer (score 2):

The common name is tall fescue which is a bunching type of grass. It is also known as K-31, K31, Kentucky fescue or pasture grass. Sometimes cheap grass seed mixes will have tall fescue seed mixed in. If you only have it in a few places then it is easier to pull it out. Each year, the bunch of tall fescue will grow larger in  diameter.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a field type fescue to me.  I hate that stuff.  Newer turf type fescues look much better.

Answer (score -1):

None of this is edible.  I recommend removing this entire greenscape and allowing weeds to grow.  Will require less water and will also most likely be an edible landscape.

Comment: chickens and cows can eat the grass

Comment: You’re right.  Or a goat.  You need a goat